# Каков оверхед от переключения контекста?

Tags: производительность, cpu, планировщик-задач

Насколько выгоднее решать вычислительную задачу без планировщика, целиком отдавая процессор под конкретную задачу? Интересует, насколько большие накладные расходы даёт переключение контекста — возможно, кто-то исследовал.

Прошу прощения, поторопился — на enSO [уже есть этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887797/what-is-the-overhead-of-a-context-switch)

Comment: По моему, основные расходы на переключение контекста происходят не от работы планировщика, а от использования системных вызовов. Вообще, переключение контекста между приложением и системой - это не очень быстрый процесс, от этого все эти lock-free структуры данных (чтобы обходиться без мьютексов) и epoll'ы, чтобы обслуживать одним вызовом несколько каналов ввода - вывода

Comment: @S.H., спасибо за отклик! Но ведь вычисления могут и не предполагать интенсивного использования системных вызовов - достаточно один раз выделить для них память в начале, запустить обработку и вывести результат в конце. А так от задачи зависит, разумеется

Comment: как я понял из оценок, приведенных в статье, вопрос именно в частоте переключения между тредами и кол-ве тредов. Если треды независимые и их "примерно как ядер cpu" - то затраты на переключение контекста не превышают 0.1%. Но при частом переключении контекста тредов (миллионы переключений в секунду) там получается заметный оверхэд.  Там в статье есть цифры